# Is eating with left hand permitted when eating with right hand is difficult and uncomfortable?

Tags: halal-haram, adab

I am a left-handed person. I have a great difficulty and discomfort in eating or drinking with my right hand. In Islam, in this situation, is it permissible to eat or drink with the left hand?